# How to add a button for Purchase order in netsuite

Tags: netsuite

i want to add a new button 'Receive',when user clicks on this button it has to generate In-transit id(number) in Purchase Order.Help me out.

Thanks,
Veera.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would add customer field to purchase order, then create a user event script with before load event (addButton, in this example) to create the button at view on the form. It would apply to purchase order. The script would look something like this:

```
            // add button to form at view
            function addButton(type,form)
            {
                if (type=='view')
                {
                form.setScript('customscript11111');   
                form.addButton('custpage_button','Receive','buttonEvent();');
                }
            }
```

Then I would have the script this calls do the work:

```
            // customscript11111
            function buttonEvent()
            {
                var Id = nlapiGetRecordId();
                // Do whatever stuff to make/get your number
                nlapiSubmitField('purchasorder', Id, 'id_name_of_customfield', valueToSet, false);
            }
```

Good luck!